# Python3x TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

The following code works on Python 2.7.x but not for Python 3.x (bytes-like-object is expected not str)
Am I missing something? Is there a better way of doing this for Python3?

```
  def vsend(self, framestring):
    totalsent = 0
    metasent = 0
    length =len(framestring)
    lengthstr=str(length).zfill(8)

    while metasent < 8 :

        sent = self.sock.send(lengthstr[metasent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Socket connection broken")
        metasent += sent


    while totalsent < length :
        sent = self.sock.send(framestring[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Socket connection broken")
        totalsent += sent
```

ERROR:
 sent = self.sock.send(lengthstr[metasent:])
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
 [ WARN:0] terminating async callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, `send` expects a byte-like object, not a string. You can convert your string to bytes by [`encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)ing it, just don't forget to [`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on the other side that receives it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error is on this line : sent = self.sock.send(lengthstr[metasent:]) .How to convert

Comment: @user9158464 Just encode the argument of `send`: `sent = self.sock.send(lengthstr[metasent:].encode())`

Comment: Thank you so much !